# How exactly is "interacting with Core.Compiler" undefined in a generated function?

Tags: reflection, compilation, julia

The docs for [generated functions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.3-dev/manual/metaprogramming/#Generated-functions-1) at some point say the following:

> Some operations that should not be attempted include:
>
> 1. ...
> 2. Interacting with the contents or methods of Core.Compiler in any way.

What exactly is meant by "interacting" in this context? Is just using things from `Core.Compiler` from within a generated function undefined behaviour?

My use case is to detect builtin functions from within an `IRTools` dynamo (which constructs generated functions), but you can refer to the following dummy code (inspired by [`Cassette.canrecurse`](https://github.com/jrevels/Cassette.jl/blob/79eabe829a16b6612e0eba491d9f43dc9c11ff02/src/context.jl#L457-L473)), which contains the actual "interactions" I want to perform:

```
julia> @generated function foo(f, args...)
           mod = Core.Compiler.typename(f).module
           is_builtin = ((f <: Core.Builtin) && !(mod === Core.Compiler))
           if is_builtin
               quote
                   println("$f is builtin")
                   f(args...)
               end
           else
               :(f(args...))
           end
       end

foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo(+, 1, 2)
3

julia> foo(Core.tuple, 1, 2)
tuple is builtin
(1, 2)
```

Which seems to work without problems.

Comment: Why not just use `Base.typename`?

Comment: Because I copied the code from Cassette, ask them :) But the general question still stands.